# Show that $n! < \frac{(n+1)^{n^2+n+1}}{(n+2)^{n^2+1}}$ for $n\ge 2$

Tags: calculus, inequality, factorial

$n! < \frac{(n+1)^{n^2+n+1}}{(n+2)^{n^2+1}}$

For very small values of $n$ (i.e. $2\le n\le 6$) the function on the right nicely approximates $n!$ before significantly overtaking it.  I don't have much work to show (unfortunately) because this is just what my calculations came down to after a rather long proof. That is to say, proving this will close up the rest of my proof.

Unfortunately, induction doesn't seem to be very helpful since (if we assume the induction hypothesis then):

$$(n+1)!=(n+1)n! < \frac{(n+1)^{n^2+n+2}}{(n+2)^{n^2+1}} \not< \frac{(n+2)^{n^2+3n+2}}{(n+3)^{n^2+2n+2}}$$

Comment: I calculate that your inequality is true for $2 \le n \le 14$ and false for $n \ge 15$. Are you sure you've transcribed it correctly?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.... I'm currently reviewing my calculations.... it seems there was a minor error.  I want to double check it AGAIN before posting another error!

Comment: Yup!  There was a very small mistake quite early on and it was unredeemable.  I'll delete this question in a few minutes, and post the question it was intended to answer as well as my attempts and why they don't work (for example the negative results from this post).

Thank you for finding the glitch!

Answer (score 3):

A small note on your bound: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3251321/631742), I showed that the suggested upper bound divided by $n!$ actually converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. So your bound is actually a lower bound of $n!$ for large $n$.

Comment: Hi.  I really appreciate your effort. 

I have to ask for help interpreting your reply and the question on the other page....  

Does your answer show that in fact my approach DOES work after we consider large enough N?  In other words, for some N it follows that for all n>N your approach works... and then we need to check manually for all m<N?  How big is N?

Comment: @Squirtle sorry to let you down : What this means is that your bound is much smaller than $n!$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If we apply Stirling approximation and Taylor expansions to
$$A_n=\log (n!)-\left(n^2+n+1\right) \log (n+1)+\left(n^2+1\right) \log (n+2)$$
$$A_n==\frac{1}{2} (\log (2 \pi n)-5)+\frac{47}{12 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$